# log4net config file for net.core with UDP Append remote address dynamically

Tags: c#, udp, ip, log4net

I got a log4net file in which I added the following : 
I want to be able to inject the RemoteAddress variable from my appSetting.json file via the startup.cs page.
But I am getting the following error :

> log4net:ERROR Could not create Appender [UdpAppender] of type [log4net.Appender.UdpAppender]. Reported error follows.
>       log4net.Util.TypeConverters.ConversionNotSupportedException: Cannot convert from type [System.String] value [%propery{RemoteAddress}] to type [System.Net.IPAddress] ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
>          at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)
>          at System.Net.Dns.ResolveCallback(Object context)

The code in the log4net file -

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
        <RemoteAddress value="%propery{RemoteAddress}" />
        <RemotePort value="5005" />
        <encoding value="utf-8"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %property{log4net:HostName} - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

I added in the startup file the following code -

```
//logging
XmlDocument log4NetConfig = new XmlDocument();
log4NetConfig.Load(File.OpenRead("log4net.config"));
var repo = log4net.LogManager.CreateRepository(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly(), typeof(log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy));
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = env.ContentRootPath + Configuration["AppSettings:Logging:LoggerPath"];
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RemoteAddress"] = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Configuration["AppSettings:Logging:RemoteAddress"]);
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(repo, log4NetConfig["log4net"]);

log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Startup)).Info($"Invoice service started. environment={env.EnvironmentName}");
```

Is it not possible to add the remote Address dynamically? When I use the actual IP address in the log4net file instead of using  `"%propery{RemoteAddress}"` and `log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RemoteAddress"] = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(Configuration["AppSettings:Logging:RemoteAddress"]);`  it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved via a custom type converter (via [`IConvertFrom`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Util_TypeConverters_IConvertFrom.htm)).
You can reuse the implementation of Log4net's [`PatternString`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Util_PatternString.htm) for the parsing of the context properties (here: `%property{RemoteAddress}`).

The type converter looks like here below, parsing and converting the configured value to an `IPAddress`.

```
public class IPAddressPatternConverter : IConvertFrom
{
    public IPAddressPatternConverter()
    {}

    public Boolean CanConvertFrom(Type sourceType)
    {
        return typeof(String) == sourceType;
    }

    public Object ConvertFrom(Object source)
    {
        String pattern = (String)source;
        PatternString patternString = new PatternString(pattern);
        String value = patternString.Format();

        return IPAddress.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

At the start of your application you register it with Log4net's `ConverterRegistry` via

```
log4net.Util.TypeConverters.ConverterRegistry.AddConverter(typeof(IPAddress), new IPAddressPatternConverter());
```

The xml configuration stays as-is:
*(Notice to specify %proper**t**y instead of %propery.)*

```
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
    <RemoteAddress  value="%property{RemoteAddress}" />
    <!-- Remaining settings. --->
</appender
```

You configure the actual IP address via the context property involved.

```
String ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RemoteAddress"] = ipAddress;
```