# log4net config file for net.core with UDP Append remote port dynamically

Tags: c#, log4net, remote-server

I have a log4net.config file in which I want to be able to inject the RemotePort variable dynamically via Program.cs file. But I am getting the following error :

```
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I was able to pass RemoteAddress dynamically with this strategy :

[log4net config file for net.core with UDP Append remote address dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813014/log4net-config-file-for-net-core-with-udp-append-remote-address-dynamically)

The code in the log4net file

```xml
<appender name="UdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
        <RemoteAddress value="%property{RemoteAddress}" />
        <RemotePort value="%property{RemotePort}" />
        <encoding value="utf-8"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level - %property{log4net:HostName} - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
```

The code in Program.cs

```
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RemotePort"] = 514;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same concept as shown in the referenced article is also applicable here.

You need a translation from a `PatternString` to an `Int32` which requires a custom type converter implementing [`IConvertFrom`](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/T_log4net_Util_TypeConverters_IConvertFrom.htm).

Reusing the implementation of a `PatternString` the `%property{RemotePort}` will be replaced by the value passed in via `log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["RemotePort"] = 514`, which will result into `514`.

```
public class NumericConverter : IConvertFrom
{
    public NumericConverter()
    {}

    public Boolean CanConvertFrom(Type sourceType)
    {
        return typeof(String) == sourceType;
    }

    public Object ConvertFrom(Object source)
    {
        String pattern = (String)source;
        PatternString patternString = new PatternString(pattern);
        String value = patternString.Format();

        return Int32.Parse(value);
    }
}
```

Register this type converter at startup as shown below

```
log4net.Util.TypeConverters.ConverterRegistry.AddConverter(typeof(int), new NumericConverter());
```