# log4net config file for UDPAppender remote address dynamically

Tags: properties, log4net

I want to configure the remote address property of the UDPAppender. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52813014/log4net-config-file-for-net-core-with-udp-append-remote-address-dynamically) article I can make it work with an IPAddress, but not a hostname. The strange thing is that if I put in a servername directly to the log4net config file it does work.

I think when I specify a property in remoteAddress the data type expected is IPAddress and it fails to parse my string into that, but perhaps it doesn't check when the hostname is hardcoded in the config file and it works by luck.
Worst case I guess I could resolve the hostname to an IPAddress and then set that as %property{ServerName}, but that seems a little awkward.

My config file contains

> ```
> <appender name="MyUdpAppender" type="log4net.Appender.UdpAppender">
>   <remoteAddress value="%property{ServerName}" />
>   <remotePort value="%property{ServerPort}"/>
>   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
>     <conversionPattern value="%message" />
>   </layout>
> </appender>
> ```